# How to make discord.py bot interact between two members of the server?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, chatbot

I am fairly new with discord bot development. I am making a bot where I need to store replies from 2 different users after the bot sends a reply as a PROMPT. I need the bot to store replies ONLY after the users got the prompt and ONLY from the users who got the prompt. Sorry for the lengthy question.

```
async def send_message(message, user_message, is_private,member):
    try:
        response = responses.get_response(user_message)  

        if is_private:
            await message.author.send(response)
            #I got a mentioned member using client.fetch_user(USER_ID)
            await member.send(response)
```

So in the above snippet, suppose the bot's sending a dm stating "Please enter a number:" to 2 users. I want each of the user to reply something that the bot will store cause it needs to work further with those replies.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I just needed some patience and some knowledge about the discord.py library. I solved the problem using some simple if-else statements.